# asp.net webapi core 3.1.self-hosted Kestrel app needs conversion to WIndows service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1

Have a working self-hosted WebApi exe using Asp.Net Core 3.1 and Kestrel and http. How can I convert that to a Windows service?

It was developed using Visual Studio 2019 Community, and also includes Serilog and Swagger, but uses a third party facilty (Actian OpenROAD Server) rather than a database.

I have searched lots of articles but nothing seems to specifically address this issue. The notes on starting from scratch using a "Worker" also do not help much and are mostly aimed at running background tasks for MVC.

Sorry but I have searched recent questions under various tags and cannot find a suitable answer.

Comment: As far as I understand, windows service mainly used to simply provide a mechanism to automatically start application on boot and restart it on failure. In many cases, you may simply create a new service and specify path to your application. Which problem have you encountered (unexpected current directory, lifetime problems, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks @metacube. Have not encountered a problem because I did not understand how to create the service. I will try your suggestion, which I had not thought of!

Comment: If PowerShell version is fresh enough you may use command ```New-Service -Name SERVICE_NAME -BinaryPathName FULL_PATH_TO_APPLICATION_EXECUTABLE```. If it is not an option, older sc.exe may be used in cmd.exe. Service identity, startup type, action on errors and other options may be easily changed via Services gui

Comment: Thanks @metacube I have used both sc and PowerShell New-Service on other jobs over many years. In this case, the Posh(5.1) command creates the Service happily but the service refuses to start, reporting a timeout. The executable starts correctly, but not the service. I have other APIs built with asp.net Framework 4.7.2 using Owin and they start happily. I am obviously missing something with Core 3.1 and Kestrel in this new API.

Comment: I have created an almost minimal web API project similar to the one I use. It works as a service without any troubles. Hope this sample will help: https://github.com/metacube/webapi-windows-service-sample

Comment: Thanks @metacube. Your example uses some interesting techniques! I will try them and add in my own Api Controllers etc..